# Non-linear optimization local or global solution

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization, nonlinear-programming, nonconvex-programming, big-m

In an NLP, I have a constraint that I would like to formulate in a convex manner preferably without introducing binary variables and/or big M formulations if possible. The actual problem is non-convex and I am happy with a local solution but I want to avoid any integer variables as there is not a good choice of open-source solvers for nonlinear problems. But of course, if it is not possible to avoid binary variables then it should be fine. The issue is to reformulate IF-THEN-ELSE condition of the type below to determine the appropriate parameter to use:
$ IF \hspace{0.5mm}\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_i{\ c}_i^t\ \ -{\ L}_t\right)\ <0$
Then $\hspace{0.5mm}\ r_t\ =\ s_t  \hspace{0.5mm}\ Else \hspace{0.5mm}\ r_t\ =\ g_t$

where

- r, s , g and L are constant parameters (time dependent)
- $x_i$ is a vector of optimisation variables (continuous)
- ${\ c}_i^t$ are coefficients of $x_i$

The actual constraint is given by:
$\sum_{t=1}^{T}{EP}_t=0\ $

where
${EP}_0\ =\ 0$

${EP}_1\ =\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_ic_i^1} - L_1$

${EP}_2\ =\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_ic_i^2} - L_2\ +\ {EP}_1\ r_1\ $

${EP}_3\ =\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_ic_i^3} - L_3\ +\ {EP}_2\ r_2\  $

${EP}_t\ =\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_ic_i^t} - L_t\ +\ {EP}_{t-1}\ r_t\ $

$If\ {EP}_{t-1}\ <0\  then \hspace{0.5mm}\ r_t\ =\ s_t \hspace{0.5mm}\
Else \hspace{0.5mm}\ r_t\ =\ g_t$

where

- $r_t, \hspace{0.5mm}\ s_t , \hspace{0.5mm}\ g_t and \hspace{0.5mm}\ L_t$ are constants
- $0\leq x_i \leq 1$ $\hspace{5mm}\ i  \in {1,2...n}$
- ${\ c}_i^t$ are coefficients of $x_i$
- Only $x_i$  are the optimisation variables

**How can this constraint be reformulated either using Big M /binary variables or using some other formulation? I don't want to use IF in the constraint as it will make the problem hard to solve. Please note that there are a number of other nonlinear constraints in the model.** I was thinking that we may be able to write it using min and max, e.g.,
${EP}_t\ =\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_ic_i^t}\ +\ min\left\{0,{EP}_{t-1}\ \right\}\ s_t\ \ +\ max\left\{0,{EP}_{t-1}\ \right\}\ g_t$
and then introduce some auxiliary variables but I am not sure where to go next.

I have given a numerical example in the attached image which explains how this constraint is constructed and where we have determined value of x.

$c = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 20 & 30 & 40\\ 
1 & 2 & 60 & 2\\ 
5 & 3 & 2 & 1\\ 
10 & 8 & 5 & 40\\ 
3 & 6 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
, \hspace{0.5mm}\ L = \begin{pmatrix}
30\\ 
60\\ 
30\\ 
20\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix} , \hspace{0.5mm}\ x = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3\\ 
x_4
\end{pmatrix}, s = \begin{pmatrix}
0.001\\ 
0.002\\ 
0.003\\ 
0.004\\ 
0.005
\end{pmatrix}
, g = \begin{pmatrix}
0.006\\ 
0.050\\ 
0.009\\ 
0.010\\ 
0.020
\end{pmatrix}$

The above constraint will be satisfied for the following values of
$x = \begin{pmatrix}
0.363034965\\
0.514820246\\
0.539183467\\
0.856864726\\
\end{pmatrix}$

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see the model is linear (besides the logical constraint) so adding the formulation with min and max in your proposal is going to end up being a big-M based MILP representation anyway (since you have to represent those operators somehow, and if you use MILP it will be a big-M method). Probably better to go for the obvious big-M model instead of hiding it in the min/max models. A convex reformulation is not possible.

Comment: Thank you @JohanLöfberg I have a number of other non-linear constraints in the model. I have just shown this constraint as it is causing me a problem. I don't know how to use Big M method in this case either. I have added more explanation in the question.

Comment: I came across this post on stackoverflow which uses something similar to min max: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58756084/how-to-convert-an-if-else-statement-to-a-linear-programming-constraint-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Introduce a binary variable $\delta_t$ to represent which case it is and $z_t$ to represent the modelled product, and your MILP model of the piecewise-affine dynamics would be

${EP}_t\ =\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_ic_i^t}\ -L_t + z_t\\ 
{EP}_{t-1}\leq (1-\delta_t)M, -(1-\delta_t)M \leq z_t - s_t{EP}_{t-1}\leq (1-\delta_t)M\\
~{EP}_{t-1}\geq -\delta_t M, -\delta_tM \leq z_t - g_t{EP}_{t-1}\leq \delta_t M$

Comment: Thank you @JohanLöfberg. I was wondering whether the last inequality should be written as: $-\delta_tM \leq z_t - g_t{EP}_{t-1}\leq \delta_t M$ and also the first equation should be: ${EP}_t\ =\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_ic_i^t}\ -L_t + z_t$

Comment: Yes, fixed typos